# Overriding a page content in a custom module

Tags: theming, 8

After looking at a bunch of modules I am still confused as to how I can take a content piece I've created (a Server), make my own custom module (servers) and do some logic so I can pass that on to a servers-template.

servers.info.yml

```
name: Servers Module
description: Creates a Servers Module
package: Servers
type: module
core: 8.x
```

servers.module

```
<?php
  function servers_theme(){
   $theme['server_page'] = [
      'variables' =>['name' => NULL],
      'template' => 'server',
    ];
    return $theme;
  }
```

And I am not sure if this is correct, but my servers.routing.yml

```
servers.server:          #Pretty sure this part doesn't matter
  path: '/node/{server}' #I'd like to have /server/{server/ but my content's url is /node/xx
  defaults:
    _title: 'Servers'
    _controller: '\Drupal\servers\Controller\Servers::getServersImplementation'
    entity_type: 'server' #Not sure if this is correct
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content' #Do I need this?
```

Controller

```
#located in servers/src/controller/Servers.php
namespace Drupal\Servers\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller for js_example pages.
 *
 * @ingroup js_example
 */
class Servers extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Accordion page implementation.
   *
   * We're allowing a twig template to define our content in this case,
   * which isn't normally how things work, but it's easier to demonstrate
   * the JavaScript this way.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A renderable array.
   */
  public function getServersImplementation($name)
  {
    return[
      '#theme'=>'server_page',
      '#name'=>$name,
    ];
  }
}
```

Absolutely nothing shows up when I've enabled the module. I know it's enabled because I can change the routing path to a node id /node/93 and that node will give me a page not found error, when without the routing I can get the content.

No errors are present in the error.log, or recent log messages. I am quite confused with this in D8, but once I can get this concept I know I will be able to understand all I need to complete my modules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the entity line, it might be breaking your routing - I'm not sure what you intended with that but if you want to declare the passed variables' entity type you need to use Options.

```
route_with_two_nodes:
  path: '/foo/{node1}/{node2}
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::foo'
  options:
    parameters:
      node1:
        type: entity:node
      node2:
        type: entity:node
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/2310425

Comment: Basically I have a content piece I created (through structure, content type, create content type) called Server. I want to be able to grab the node id of the server in the path. That's why I used {server} but it is  not working. I added options: parameters: server: type:entity:server and still won't render.

Comment: Hmm I think I need to register server as an entity? I thought maybe creating a content type for server meant that server as an entity existed. I guess I am wrong?

Comment: Okay so forgot that Server is a content type is a node, so I changed it back to path:'/node/{server}' and set in options:parameters:server: type: entity:node but it still wont show up when I go to /node/93 (which is a server)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't want to declare a new entity type. You are generating a custom page. This is not connected to entities and nodes. Don't use `/node/{id}`, because this is already in use. The path `/server/{server}` is fine, where {server} is the parameter for the controller. You have to use identical names:

```
path: '/server/{server}'

public function getServersImplementation($server)
```